# Eigenvalue of diagonally dominant matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to ask a question about eigenvalue  of diagonally dominant matrices.

The question is :

Assume $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,
\cdots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. $A$ satisfies:

$(1):$ $a_{ii}>0~~,i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

$(2):$ $a_{ij}<0~~,i\ne j$.

$(3):$ $a_{ii}>-\sum_{i\ne j}a_{ij}~~,i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

I would like to ask if there is $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda_i)\ge\vert \mathrm{Im}(\lambda_i)\vert,~~ i=1,2,\cdots,n$ ?

I think it might have something to do with the estimation of the eigenvalues of the diagonal dominance matrix.
Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Maybe it is not true and I can't find an counterexample.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be true if you had $a_{ii}>-2\sum_{i\ne j}a_{ij}$ using the Gerschgörin circle theorem, in case that's useful to you, but with only your condition there might be counterexamples. That's only my guess though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose an $n \geq 3$, and consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1& -1& 0& \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots \\
\cdots & & & &\\
-1 & 0&0&\cdots&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix has characteristic equation
$$(1 -x)^n=1$$
which implies that it’s eigenvalues are $1-z_n^i$ for the roots of unity $z_n$.

Now consider the matrix $A-\epsilon J+ 3n\epsilon I$. Here J is the all-one matrix. For sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, this matrix satisfies all constraints to the problem. Furthermore, its spectrum converges to the spectrum of $A$ as $\epsilon$ goes to zero.

In particular, even for $n=6$ setting $\epsilon$ sufficiently close to zero gives a counter example for your conjecture given by $i=2$.

Exercise: Prove that the set of possible eigenvalues of matrices satisfying your constraint is precisely the right half plane.

Comment: In your example, $a_{ii}\not>-\sum_{i\ne j}a_{ij}~~,i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

Comment: Sure, but one can perturb the entries slightly to make this happen, unless I am misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: Some intuitions may look correct, but are proved false rigorously.

Comment: I made everything completely rigorous. Happy?

Comment: Thanks  for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

It isn’t clear whether the statement you want to prove/disprove is
$$
\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)\ge|\operatorname{Im}(\lambda)|
\ \text{ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$}\tag{1}
$$
or
$$
\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)\ge|\operatorname{Im}(\lambda)|
\ \text{ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.}\tag{2}
$$
The answer by abacaba has given a beautiful counterexample to $(1)$. Below we shall prove statement $(2)$. Let $D$ and $F$ be the diagonal and off-diagonal parts of $A$ respectively. Then $DF,\,FD$ are hollow matrices and $D^2,F^2$ are entrywise nonnegative. Therefore
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^2)
=\operatorname{tr}\big((D+F)^2\big)
=\underbrace{\operatorname{tr}(D^2)}_{\ge0}+\underbrace{\operatorname{tr}(DF)}_{=0}
+\underbrace{\operatorname{tr}(FD)}_{=0}+\underbrace{\operatorname{tr}(F^2)}_{\ge0}
\ge0.
$$
Hence $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda^2)\ge0$ for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, i.e., $|\operatorname{Arg}(\lambda^2)|\le\frac{\pi}{2}$. As $A$ is a strictly diagonally dominant matrix with a real positive diagonal, we also have $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)>0$. Therefore $|\operatorname{Arg}(\lambda)|\le\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)\ge|\operatorname{Im}(\lambda)|$.

Comment: I want to prove statement $(1)$.  Abacaba  has given a beautiful answer. But I still appreciate your proof of statement $2$.